# Having a default port when running tests in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, selenium, rspec, capybara

Im trying to run my tests with
`rake spec` 
Im using rspec,capybara with selenium as webdriver. The problem is when ever I try to run the specs It starts up the testing environment in a different port every time. I don't want this to happen as it messes up my Facebook login. 
How would I make the environment start in the same port every time.
pls help!

Answer (score 0):

Look in config/initializers/webservice.rb and try setting the config.port value to something...I'm not entirely sure this will actually do what you want but it's worth looking into.

Comment: There is no such file for me.(Im using Rails 3.0 if that is of any help)

Comment: hm, I'm in 3.0 as well. I don't remember doing anything to make that appear there. I'm installing another .rvm rails project and I'll see if/when it appears...