# Rails application's port number in a rspec test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I would like to test the json responses of a rails application using rspec in combination with faraday and faraday_middleware. To use faraday one needs the application URL. In the tests I would like to use localhost + a port number.

The question is, how can I get or set the port number of the current application instance in a rspec test environment?

There are a similar questions but no satisfying answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6807268/rails-port-of-testing-environment) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6506343/having-a-default-port-when-running-tests-in-ruby-on-rails).

Any ideas?

Comment: Am in need of the exact same thing. Hope you get an answer.

Comment: Just posted a response to a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17496025/535171).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same need (Watir+RSpec), but the problem is: there is no Rack stack running by default during tests...

I found this solution:

In `spec_helper.rb`:

```
HTTP_PORT = 4000

test_instance_pid = fork do
  exec 'unicorn_rails -E test -p %d' % HTTP_PORT
end

at_exit do
  Process.kill "INT", test_instance_pid
  Process.wait
end
```

Which start the test stack once for all spec tests, and kill it at the end. *(In this sample, I am using unicorn, but we can imagine using any other server)*

In the spec, I reuse the `HTTP_PORT` constant to build URL:

```
browser.goto "http://localhost:#{HTTP_PORT}/"
```